# jquery offset and fixed position bug

Tags: jquery, position, offset, fixed

I found out that [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will be relative to the parent element if it has the CSS property `position:fixed;`

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6aum/)

But it should be relative to the document, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was wrong. jQuery offset is relative do the document. Change your javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#child').click(function(){
        alert($(this).offset().top);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't use .offset() ... it uses offsetTop of the DOM element. I [changed the example](http://jsfiddle.net/vRFkQ/) to .offset() and it is relative to the document, as foreseen.